# Issue with for cycle in python

Tags: python

sometimes i get in my function error like this.

```
    groupId = cursor.fetchone()[0]
  File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 507, in pymssql.Cursor.fetchone
```

But not always. groupFilter get value like this `test1,test2,test3` sometimes can get only `test1` or `test2`  my function look like this.

```
elif groupFilter:
    OneMoreList = 'WHERE groupId = '
    lst = groupFilter.split(",")
    for element in groupFilter.split(","):
        print(element)
        groupId = element
        cursor.execute("SELECT groupId from dbo.CalGroups WHERE groupName='{0}'".format(groupId))
        groupId = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        if len(lst) == 1:
            OneMoreList = OneMoreList + str(groupId)
            print(OneMoreList)
        else:
            OneMoreList = OneMoreList + str(groupId) + ' AND groupId = '     
            print(OneMoreList)
    if len(lst) > 1:         
       OneMoreList = OneMoreList[-15]
       print(":)")
       print(OneMoreList)
```

any idea where is the problem?

Comment: That initial error doesn't look complete? what is the exception?

Comment: i know, but how to change it and dont lose point of getting group name id?